# Select records between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file which will get inputs from another php file and show the data in a html table, but in the sql statement I dont get the date field filtered in it, may be the date format is incorrect. Please help me with this

My Code is below

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_select_db("marketnews", $con);




$date1 = explode('/', $_POST['ADate']);
$time = mktime(0,0,0,$date1[0],$date1[1],$date1[2]);
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time );


$date2 = explode('/', $_POST['BDate']);
$time = mktime(0,0,0,$date2[0],$date2[1],$date2[2]);
$mysqldate1 = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time );

$sec= "$_POST[id]";


echo "<br>";
echo "$mysqldate1";
echo "<br>";
echo "$sec";*/


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mktnews where security = '$sec' and eventdate    between '$mysqldate' and '$mysqldate1'");
echo '<a href="main.html"><b>BACK</b></a>';
echo "<br>";
echo "<table border='2' BORDERCOLOR=GREEN align='center' >
<tr>
<th>Firm</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>NIC</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['eventdate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['news'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['security'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

date format of this MySql table is like this

2013-04-11

Please help me with this

Comment: what is the data type of your date column.. ?

Comment: And one suggestion .. please avoid using mysql_* functions they are depreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format looks correct depending on the structure of your table, however you're missing quotations in your mysql statement.

should look like this:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mktnews where security = '".$sec."' and eventdate    between '".$mysqldate."' and '".$mysqldate1."'");
```

as I'm sure you know, you should escape your queries too.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to change date format to compare as date format in your mysql table

use

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d', $time ); instead of $mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time );
```

and

```
$mysqldate1 = date( 'Y-m-d', $time ); instead of $mysqldate1 = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time );
```

will return result as you want.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time );
```

to

```
 $mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d', $time );
```

and same for `$mtsqldate1`

your php time format and mysql time format are different